# Using a hard-coded set of values in place of a traditional Eloquent model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'd like to create a many-to-many relationship between two things: **Notes** and **Labels**. However, I'd like to define the labels themselves in code rather than having them in a database table.

Aside from a `notes` table to represent the Note model, I expect to have a "pivot" table (`labels_notes`) with two columns: `note_id` and `label`.

So, my question is: **How would eager loading, getter, setter and "get notes by label" methods on the Note model work?**

*Background:* The primary reason for wanting the Labels in code rather than as content of a table is that they are a small, fixed set of values; users will not be allowed to modify them. Further, there may need to be special logic in the code around certain labels. I considered storing them in a JSON column on `notes`, but am concerned about the performance impact when searching for Notes by Label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I opted for was to use a traditional Eloquent model for Labels (including a dedicated database table), but **inject the desired values into it via the migration, and use a string primary key.** That way we're able to use Eloquent in it's intended manner rather than fighting against it.

Using a string primary key means we can write logic based around specific Labels without worrying about arbitrary numeric IDs (i.e., "id=news" vs "id=12112"). Note that doing this also requires adding `public $incrementing = false;` in the Label model class.

Injecting the necessary Labels via migration lets us avoid having an additional setup task when deploying, and also avoids coupling our code with an external process.